# how to register my dll in excel 2007

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, vsto, excel-2007

hi i have a created an Excel Add in(which creates a new ribbon for excel 2007) using vs2008-vsto-c# and also created a setup project... i install the setup project on other machine, then go to the installed folder, where i see all .dll files, including my project name .dll, let's say ExcelAddIn.dll

please can you tell me what should i do now? in order to see the same ribbon on other machine's excel 2007? thanks...

Answer (score 2):

you need to sign your assembly, before you make the installer from the project properties, and then make the installer again and try !

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on developing excel addin.

You can use Tools -> Addins & browse to the folder containing your dll. Finding that in Excel 2007 will be another question.

See if [this](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/installing-an-add-in-in-excel-2007/) helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would read the MS documentation on this one (uses Windows Installer rather than ClickOnce):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc563937.aspx

The whole point being that your installer needs to add some information to the registry so Excel knows about your addin.  Best to just use what's already out there than anything else.

I would also take a look at this SO post if you want to use ClickOnce: [Creating a (ClickOnce) setup for VSTO Outlook Add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654185/creating-a-clickonce-setup-for-vsto-outlook-add-in)

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way to do this was via a vbs script, rather than duplicate I'll post the link to someone else's helpful post on how to do this.

- [Automatically entering an Excel Addin](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=313125&page=484)